# C# script to change certain values evey repetition

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of a script that takes a block of text, and repeats it many times only changing certain values evey repetition, by following a certain formula. I would like to write it in C# but i dont have the time.
Here is an example:
The script would take the string: `"rotate(myposition, 5)"`
and after it is executed it would return:

```
rotate(myposition, 5)
rotate(myposition, 10)
rotate(myposition, 15)
rotate(myposition, 20)
rotate(myposition, 25)
```

This would spare me a lot of work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it sufficient to hard-code the way to generate the string, or does it need to receive arbitrary user input and use a user-defined formula?

Comment: And what is the formula?

Comment: *I would like to write it in C# but i dont have the time* and *This would spare me a lot of work* reflect why your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please post the code you tried and explain the problems you encountered.

Comment: This forum is to help you solves your issues, not to implement your code to save your time. Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Off-topic: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic* for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @NicholasCarey, this question isn't asking for a recommended tool, library or favorite off-site resource.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the edit, the comments and the answers. I will try to make my own script using the answers below. The formula should be arbitrary, as should also be the text. I would mainly use it to edit multiple similar elements in css. While researching i have found that converting any formatted text to string is almost impossible, but i guess that with some sacrifices it could still save me a lot of work.

Comment: @Sam Ideally I would like it to function with arbitrary user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use   `Enumerable.Range` and `String.Format`:

```
string pattern = "rotate(myposition, {0})";
int num = 5;
int count = 5;
IEnumerable<string> rotates = Enumerable.Range(1, count)
    .Select(i => string.Format(pattern, num * i));
```

If you need it as string where each part is separated by new-line:

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rotates);
```

Comment: Thanks! These are very complete methods that could help me make the text and functions arbitrary very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
for(int i = 1; i =< 10; ++i)
{
     string MyStr = "rotate(myposition, ";
     MyStr += (i * 5) + ")";
     Console.WriteLine(MyStr);
}
//Do this as many times as you want (change the 10 to the desired amount)
```

Hope this helps :)